# how to use a query result() value in another query[codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**Update**

All of your methods work. Thanks @NiloySaha, @AeroX, @Ray, @SusheelMishra.

But what if I want to compare more fields such as work experience, salary, etc? 
@Ray do I just add more params like so

```
function check_job_adverts($age, $experience, $salary){

}
```

?

or how would I approach this?
I am relevantly new to this, so please excuse me if I ask noobish questions..

---

I have the following:

```
function age() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            $id = $row->id_number;
            $dobs = substr($id, 0, 6);
            $dob = str_split($dobs, 2);
            $day = date('d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[2], 0));
            $month = date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob[1] + 1, 0, 0));
            $year = date('o', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[0] + 1));
            $date = "$day/$month/$year";
            //explode the date to get month, day and year
            $date = explode("/", $date);
            //get age from date or birthdate
            $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $date[2]) - 1) : (date("Y") - $date[2]));
            return $age;
        }
```

I want to know how to use the $age variable in another query. for example:
I want to compare `$age` with a `job_advert` table which can have an age requirement, and then display all in membership table that meets the required age from `job_advert`.

Comment: returning value from a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
function age() {
    $data   = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    foreach ($query as $key=>$row) {
        $id = $row->id_number;
        $dobs = substr($id, 0, 6);
        $dob = str_split($dobs, 2);
        $day = date('d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[2], 0));
        $month = date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob[1] + 1, 0, 0));
        $year = date('o', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[0] + 1));
        $date = "$day/$month/$year";
        //explode the date to get month, day and year
        $date = explode("/", $date);
        //get age from date or birthdate
        $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $date[2]) - 1) : (date("Y") - $date[2]));
        #return $age;                       #not returning the age now instead inserting in a array
        $data[$key]['id'] = $id;
        $data[$key]['age'] = $age;
    }
    $data = $this->another_funcion_call($data);     #calling another function which will recieve the array of ids / age
    return $data;
}

function another_funcion_call($arrayOfIdsAge){
    //loop through the array and do something
    foreach($arrayOfIdsAge as $key=>$each){
        echo "ID :".$each['id'].' AGE : '.$each['age'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I loop through the array in `function another_funcion_call($arrayOfIdsAge)`? sorry if its a noobish questuion.

Comment: Changed above answer, check.

Answer (score 0):

If i am guessing right you need to compare years.
So use column instead of m, d, y

```
select FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2013-07-19','2013-05-10'))
```

Comment: I am getting the age from a South African ID number which if formatted `9109205021082` which of the first 6 digits are `YYmmDD`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql to calculate the age of the person rather then doing it in PHP thus eliminating the need to run multiple queries.

```
SELECT YEAR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), DATE(CONCAT( LEFT(id_number,2), '-', MID(id_number,3,2), '-', MID(id_number,5,2) ))) ) AS AGE
```

Something like the above should work to convert the first 6 chars of the id_number into a date and compare it to the current date and get the difference in years.

Comment: I tested the query you gave me, but it doesnt seem to work.. it returns NULL for all in `AGE`.

Comment: I don't have mysql installed to debug this but try breaking the query up and seeing where it's failing. Try running the `SELECT DATE(CONCAT( LEFT(id_number,2), '-', MID(id_number,3,2), '-', MID(id_number,5,2) ))` bit to see if that makes a valid date first, if it doesn't then peal the DATE() bit off and check the concat result etc.

Comment: there is a flaw in the query... I have tried multiple different ways of doing this.. if I enter an id number eg. "570920.." it picks the year up as `2057` and so gives me a negative value...

Comment: You could force it to interoperate as 1957 by prefixing '19'+ before the year part; at the moment it's leaving it to server to decided which century a 2 digit year falls in. This is a short coming of storing dates in a 2 digit format. You could take the current year in two digit format and say if year is higher then it then prefix '19' else prefix '20' onto the two digit year.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example if you dont want to call it in the same function as age();

```
function age() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $id = $row->id_number;
        $dobs = substr($id, 0, 6);
        $dob = str_split($dobs, 2);
        $day = date('d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[2], 0));
        $month = date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob[1] + 1, 0, 0));
        $year = date('o', mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dob[0] + 1));
        $date = "$day/$month/$year";
        //explode the date to get month, day and year
        $date = explode("/", $date);
        //get age from date or birthdate
        $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]))) >     date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $date[2]) - 1) : (date("Y") - $date[2]));
        return $age;
    }

function check_job_adverts($age){
// here goes your job_advert checking function
// example.. run an array to match ages vs jobs
// mind the array return if multiple options
}




$age = age();
// somewhere else in your script make the call with $age
$fetchJobs = check_job_adverts($age);
```